# Angularjs ng-src and phonegap read file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have an app that needs to read an image file that I have saved to the device.

I have everything working execpt one small problem getting the file returned to ng-src. I now that the problem is with returning the value from a nested function I'm just not sure how to fix it.

HTML

```
<img ng-src="{{getImage(product.image_a_225_x_225)}}" width="120px" height="120px" />
```

the getImage function

```
$scope.getImage = function(image){
    var img = "";
    GapFile.readFile("255_images/"+image, false, function(evt){
        img =  evt;
        //console.log(evt)
    });
    return img;

};
```

I know this is not going to work because img returns before GapFile.readFile is finished. I have tested that GapFile.readFile is outputing good base-64 to the console and that if hard coded that base-64 gets back to ng-src correctly. But how can I get that nested success function to return to ng-src

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hack you could do would be to $scope.$apply once the image is loaded (though I would seriously recommend looking at how you are doing things rather than abuse $scope.$apply).

```
var _allImages = {};
$scope.getImage = function(image){
    if (_allImages[image]) {
        return _allImages[image];
    }
    GapFile.readFile("255_images/"+image, false, function(evt){
        _allImages[image] =  evt;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
    return __base64BlankImage__;

};
```

Comment: Works like a charm without $scope.$apply() Thanks

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think the readFile callback would force Angular update.